# File crashes Windows Explorer and is undeletable

Tags: windows-7, command-line, windows-explorer, wmv

I'm running Windows 7, brand new Dell Vostro laptop with Intel i7, 500 gb hard drive and 8 gigs of RAM. Recently used it for video editing, leading to the creation of this file.

This file, which used to be a video file (.wmv, converted from AVI using VLC Media Player), we'll call it "file.wmv". Every time I tried to move it or delete it, Windows Explorer would open the dialog box "discovering" and would sit there and do nothing. If i closed it, another dialog box would pop up, without a title, supposedly the actual move/delete box, but still do nothing. After trying to do these things, if I went anywhere else on my computer, Windows Explorer would be incredibly slow and take a very long time to show the contents of a file, even going as far as showing the "loading" bar at 99% and then hovering there forever.
So i finally realized that this was the file's fault, not a program i had recently installed (which incidentally happened to be open at the same time as me trying to work with the file), so i shut everything off and tried to rename it, seeing if there was a difference. after editing the file extension, Windows Explorer would become unresponsive, and upon restarting Windows Explorer, every time I try and open a folder or the control panel, I get a warning that looks like this:

> explorer.exe:
>
> the remote call procedure failed and did not execute.

Now, i restarted the computer and Windows Explorer ran fine. I tried renaming it again, because the file reset to being a '.wmv'. WE crashes again. i know how to use the command prompt, so i opened up the file's location in `cmd.exe` and tried renaming it to 'file.abc'. This works, but then i try deleting it:

> >del file.abc
>
> Access is Denied.

I've tried using `runas` to run `del` as an admin, but the problem is that I am the admin. There should be no access denied, i have full rights. I can't use `runas` with the Administrator account because when i do, i get the error "1327: user account restriction" The "Computer Management" window also tells me that the Administrator account is disabled.

I get the same message with any other operation i preform on the file, including renaming it.

Rebooting my computer fixes Windows Explorer, but not the file's ability to screw it up.

What do I do? I am out of options and understanding. I need this file off my system, because it is terrible and screwed up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to run the command prompt as admin, i.e. right click on command prompt and run as administrator? If it is run as admin, the working directory is C:\Windows\system32.

Another possible way is to run Windows in [Safe Mode](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ss/safe-mode-windows-7.htm) and use the command prompt.
before running `del` use `dir` in the directory of the file to check that the file is actually present and has the correct filename.

Comment: I didn't know about running as administrator. thanks.

Comment: Just as background information: You are not admin on a modern windows. You usually as a regular user with the option to elevate to admin. This is why the 'run as' method worked and why having the admin account disabled was not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check if a process has grabbed the file and locked it (possibly even WE). I've successfully used unlocker to solve this problem - you can find it here:

It will try to unlock the file & even if it's not locked, gives you some other options for overcoming the problem you describe:

[image: unlocker example]

There are other unlockers out there, too - if this one fails, don't give up.

In addition, following up on Pincopallino's suggestion, you can try booting from a DOS diskette or a [Bart PE](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/) disk & there's a good chance you'll be able to get rid of the file from one of those environments.

Good luck!